# A diferença entre Software Service e Standalone

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, instalador, standalone

Tenho uma dúvida sobre `Softwares` que funcionam como `Service` e outros que funcionam como `Standalone`.

**Software Service (background process)**

> Um processo em segundo plano é um processo de computador que roda "nos
>   bastidores" (ou seja, no fundo) e sem intervenção do usuário.
>
> [Background Process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_process)

**Software Standalone**

> São chamados stand Alone , ou stand-alone (literalmente "ficam em pé por si só") os programas completamente auto-suficientes: para seu funcionamento não necessitam de um software auxiliar, como um interpretador, sob o qual terão de ser executados.
>
> [Wikipedia/Standalone](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standalone)

1. **Nota:** Usei o `background process`, pois foi o mais próximo de um
   *serviço background* que encontrei. A palavra `service`, `serviço` e etc, fica fora do escopo assuntos.
2. **Nota:** Estou usando termo `Service` e `Standalone`, por que vi um programa que trás as duas opções de instalação e preciso entender o por que.

---

1. Qual a diferença entre os dois tipos?
2. Quando um software for `standalone` posso aceitar que ele é "backgroud process"? Ou vice versa.
3. Acredito que se um programa tem essas duas opções para instalação deve existir uma diferença.

Comment: Você tem um exemplo de programa que ofereça essas duas opções? Vi que você aceitou minha resposta, mas talvez ela não se aplique ao seu caso - pois uma coisa é o ciclo de vida do sistema (quem inicia, quem termina, como o usuário interage com ele) e outra são suas dependências (se ele está "amarrado" à configuração atual do SO ou não).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Nota:** se os dois termos são apresentados como opções na instalação de um sistema, então provavelmente eles se referem à maneira como **as dependências** desse sistema serão gerenciadas - e não à maneira como *o ciclo de vida* do programa é gerenciado (como minha resposta assume). Ver a [resposta do Cigano Morrison Mendez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11348/215) para mais detalhes.

Os dois conceitos são ortogonais, ou seja, não tem relação alguma um com o outro. Você pode ter um sistema que é *standalone* **e** um *background process*, você pode ter um que é só um ou só outro, e você pode ter um que não é nenhum dos dois.

Como explicado na [resposta do Cigano Morrison Mendez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11348/215), um aplicativo *standalone* é auto-suficiente, possuindo tudo o que precisa para funcionar sem a dependência de aplicativos externos. Entretanto, há um limite - programas são normalmente compilados para uma arquitetura específica, e normalmente também para um sistema operacional específico. Isso significa que há sim dependência em relação ao SO, só não há em relação a **outros** aplicativos e bibliotecas que não são parte nativa desse SO. Mesmo um sistema distribuído no formato código-fonte exige no mínimo um compilador para transformá-lo em código executável.

Já o conceito de serviço, é mais ou menos o seguinte: quando o sistema operacional inicia, uma série de outros programas são postos em execução, até que o mesmo esteja pronto para receber comandos do usuário (seja via interface gráfica ou via terminal). Todos esses programas são chamados "serviços" (com exceção dos aplicativos "normais" que o usuário optou por iniciar ao "ligar o computador"). Normalmente não possuem uma janela, ou um ícone na barra de tarefas, e a única maneira de interagir com eles é através da sua interface de serviço (que pode ser via socket, pipe, requisições http, etc). Também não podem ser "abertos" ou "fechados" pelo usuário (exceto fechamento forçado), pois seu ciclo de vida é controlado pelo próprio SO.

Cabe notar que *background process* é diferente de *service*: em sistemas *NIX pelo menos, qualquer processo pode ser enviado para o *background* (e posteriormente trazido de volta para o *foreground*) através de um comando específico. Mas isso não o torna um serviço - pois se você fechar o terminal/fizer logout, todos os processos que aquele terminal iniciou são fechados também. Para o processo "sobreviver ao fechamento", é necessário que ele tenha sido explicitamente configurado para isso (como descrito anteriormente).

(e caso isso não esteja claro, "enviar para o background" significa que o terminal fica livre para executar outros comandos; ou no caso de uma interface gráfica, significa que o programa deixa de ter uma janela)

Comment: A exemplo das opções de instalação do Firebird Database, que lhe pergunta se será instalado como aplicação ou serviço? Isso no Windows. Quando instalado como serviço você não o "vê". Mas quando instalado como aplicação ele ja lhe da um ícone para iteração no quick laucher.

Answer (score 4):

`Background Process` é dependente do sistema operacional e gerenciado por ele. Portanto, está sujeito a mudanças de comportamento com atualizações e migrações. Normalmente é menor e não requer muita configuração.

`Standalone` normalmente indica que o aplicativo é autosuficiente. Possui todas as bibliotecas pra funcionar independente da instalação do sistema operacional. Apesar de ser maior e requerer mais configurações, o `Standalone` é mais indicado para estabilidade e para servidores que recebam atualizações contínuas que possam prejudicar o funcionamento do aplicativo.

Comment: Me esclarece uma dúvida: no contexto da pergunta ("Estou usando termo Service e Standalone, por que vi um programa que trás as duas opções de instalação e preciso entender o por que.") é comum **um mesmo software** oferecer as duas modalidades tal como descrito na sua resposta (i.e. instalar só o que precisa ou instalar tudo)? Desculpe a ignorância, mas não tenho experiência com instalação de sistemas completos em servidores... (só conheço sistemas que ou empacotam as dependências ou não empacotam) Se a resposta for "sim" então de fato *esta* deveria ser a resposta correta.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Servidores de aplicação ou de banco de dados normalmente possuem essas opções, sobretudo para Windows. Há a opção de se instalar o software como serviço (em `Background Process`) ou então de forma autônoma (`Standalone`). Há algumas opções para Linux, mas normalmente no Linux já é `Standalone` pela dependência de pacotes.